# Laravel Model must return a relationship instance

Tags: laravel

My website has comments. These comments can have "votes", upvotes and downvotes.

I have a Comment Model and a CommentVote model.

In my comment model I have a functions that returns the votes:

```
public function votes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommentVote', 'comment_id');
}

public function upvotes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommentVote', 'comment_id')->where('vote', 1);
}   

public function downvotes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommentVote', 'comment_id')->where('vote', -1);
}
```

Notice that upvotes are stored in the database in a tinyInt as `1` and downvotes are stored as `-1`

In my CommentVote model I have the belongsTo relationship:

```
public function comment() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment');
}
```

Now I want to have a function that calculates the total "score" of the comment. Total upvotes minus total downvotes.

I try to make a function that counts all the upvotes - all the downvotes.

```
public function score() {
    return $this->upvotes()->count() - $this->downvotes()->count();
}
```

This returns the error:

> App\Comment::score must return a relationship instance.

In fact using the `count()` anywhere will return this error, despite it working fine in my other Models.

Doing something simple like:

```
public function voteCount() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CommentVote', 'comment_id')->count();
    or even
    return $this->votes()->count();
}
```

will return the error:

> App\Comment::voteCount must return a relationship instance.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT:**

Here is the controller, as per requests in the comments:

```
public function getSubmission($subchan, $id, $URLtitle) {

    $submission = Submission::where('id', $id)->first();
    $comments = Comment::where('submission_id', $submission->id)->where('parent_id', NULL)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

    $comments = $comments->sortByDesc(function($comment){
        return count($comment['upvotes']) - count($comment['downvotes']);
    });     

    if (!$submission) {
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('error', 'Submission not found.' );
    }       

    return view('submissions.submission')
    ->with('submission', $submission)
    ->with('navSubchan', $submission->getSubchan->name)
    ->with('submissionPage', 1)
    ->with('comments', $comments)
    ;

}
```

Comment: Where and how are you using `public function score()` and `public function voteCount()`?

Comment: the comment model

Comment: I mean what does the code that calls those functions look like? `Comment::with(["score"])`? `$score = $comment->score`? Etc etc

Comment: @FelixMaxime That answers the "where". What about the how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you're doing `$model->score`, which is going to look for a function called `score()`, but in a specific manner that expects that function to return a `HasMany`, `HasOne`, `BelongsTo` etc. style relationship object.

Consider [an accessor function](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) instead.

```
public function getScoreAttribute() {
    return $this->upvotes()->count() - $this->downvotes()->count();
}
```

allows you to do `$model->score` successfully.

Comment: Side note: Given your data structure and values, you might consider `$this->votes()->sum('vote')` to reduce queries.

Comment: This still returns getScoreAttribute must return a relationship instance"

Comment: Then you need to show us how you're calling this, because that makes no sense. You'd have to be doing something like `$model->load('score')` or eager loading with `with('score')`.

Comment: I can post the entire models if that helps

Comment: @FelixMaxime It's probably not the model. It's where you're trying to output/use the `score` value - probably a controller or view.

Comment: Post the controller (or view) code where you're using these functions.

Comment: @TimLewis posted the controller function in my main post

Comment: @FelixMaxime The new code you posted doesn't have the word 'score' in it anywhere. **We need the code that uses the score in some way.** Getting its value, printing its value, etc.

Comment: Score is a completely made up function name in the model. It's simply a function that counts all the upvotes minus all the downvotes. Instead of "score" it could just be called "getUpvotesMinusDownvotesCount".

Comment: @FelixMaxime You won't get the error you're reporting without **using** the score somewhere. Somewhere in your code - maybe in `resources/views/submissions/submission.blade.php`? - you do something like `$foo->score` that's causing Laravel to attempt to execute the `score()` function

Comment: In the blade template. "<div>
score: {{ $comment->getScoreAttribute}} </div>"

Also I just figured out my problem. It should have been $comment->getScoreAttribute()

Comment: No, it should be `$comment->score` to use the accessor. It should be `$comment->score()` if you use the non-accessor approach you had in your original question.

Comment: You don't literally call `comment->getScoreAttribute`... Laravel translates the function name to the attribute, so for `get{...}Attribute`, you'd call whatever `...` is, so `$comment->score`.

Comment: `$foo->bar` is a magic Laravel functionality that says "if the parameter doesn't directly exist, try to find a relationship function (and it must *be* a relationship function) called `bar()` OR an accessor function called `getBarAttribute()`".